# Upgrading Image analysis from 8->16 bit quanta; store calculations in Int32, Float or Double?

Tags: c, image, performance, memory, rgb

I am doing some scientific calculations on images in C and currently use ImageMagick to read a file and output a 8 bit quanta raw RGB file to analyze. I am seeing recurring squares in the output and some garbled, fuzzy regions. Suspect integer truncation is causing the artifacts.

After I read the entire 8 bit, RGB file into memory, I allocate a parallel array of unsigned shorts to hold intermediate results during the analysis. The calculations are all done with doubles and stored as unsigned shorts which can be used in other calculations. At the end, the shorts are dumped to disk and read back into either Photoshop or ImageMagick as a raw, 16 bit RGB images.

With only 8 bits of input data, the granularity is fairly chunky especially on darker areas where single digit RGB values are common. Even when working with all 8 neighboring data points in an operation such as averaging them all, I can store the full values of all points and still have 16 - 8 - 3 = 5 bits left before overflowing the unsigned shorts. From experience, you get ugly, muddy, mangled areas when the overflow causes loss of higher level bits.

I plan on upgrading the input to full, 16 bit, unsigned short, TIFF type quanta. Upgrading the parallel, working array to full, 32 bit integers would make any possibility of overflow vanishingly remote. Doubles would also work fine, but are soooo large and seem like overkill. I am already doubling the memory requirements by working with 2 byte data rather than 8 bit and doubles would pile 8 bytes on top of that per channel per pixel. I am dreading the performance hit this is bound to cause.

I think floats might suffice. With 16 bit raw data being stored in their 23 bit significands, 7 bits of extra space would be available. Using the current next-neighbor, 8 pixel cache, I would still have 4 bits spare space before overflowing. An operation as simple as averaging 2 neighbors deep for 24 total neighbors would require 5 bits leaving as few as 2 bits spare before overflowing.

The current memory requirements for a 36 MPix image are 36 * (3 bytes for image + 6 bytes for calculations) = 36x9 = 324 MB, 108 MB read from disk and 216 written back to a different file, both on a fast SSD.

Upgrading to 16 bit input and using 4 byte int32 or float parallel:  36 MPix (6 bytes/pixel primary +12 bytes/pixel parallel) = 36*18 = 648MB.  Plus 216 MB disk read/write

With doubles: 36 * (6 + 24) = 1080MB. 3.33 X current memory. Plus 216 MB disk read/write

Doing purely integer operations now, I can crunch a 108 MB, 36 MPix file in 3.41 seconds with gcc/32. Adding a pow() to the computational mix raises the time to 28.48s for the same binary

Short of writing 3 variations and benchmarking them all, any ideas on which storage will be the fastest, int32, float or double???  Better compiler?

```
===========================================================================
Results with current 8 bit input, 16 bit storage and 16 bit output. 
The fastest in integer is the slowest in floating point. 

ran 12 times, 4 binaries, tcc, gcc32, gcc64 and msvc
Test "0" is purely integer, test "1" uses integer and double pow()
1498 sec 12 runs -> 
%time       Binary        Test   Average     Compiler + Optimizations
22.815% -> raw2cv.gcc32     1   28.48s
22.804% -> raw2cv.gcc64     1   28.47s
19.246% -> raw2cv.tcc       1   24.03s
18.489% -> raw2cv           1   23.08s
6.513% -> raw2cv.tcc        0   8.13s       tcc, no optimizations
4.661% -> raw2cv            0   5.82s       msvc /O2 
2.741% -> raw2cv.gcc64      0   3.42s       mingw -O3 -ffast-math -m64
2.732% -> raw2cv.gcc32      0   3.41s       mingw -O3 -ffast-math

tcc version 0.9.26 (x86-64 Win64)
gcc version 4.7.3 (release with patches / build 20130526 by strawberryperl.com)
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
```

Comment: And,
Asus P8P67 Pro motherboard
Intel Sandy Bridge 2700k 3.4Ghz overclocked  to 4.3 GHz
32GB G.Skill Ripjaws DDR3 1600 (slightly overclocked) cl9
windows 7 pro 64
Samsung 830 SSD with ~500MB/s

Comment: Note: a typical [float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has a 24 bit significand, not 23.  23 bits stored explicitly, 1 implied.

Comment: With `float`, is code using `pow()` or `powf()`?

Comment: I am using the double pow(). All of the intermediate code uses doubles and then stores the result in an unsigned short before moving on to the next pixel. PowF() should be faster.

Comment: Seeing how code uses `pow()`, etc. may elicit ideas to do the same faster and without FP.  In general, fastest code will be integer only and most flexible code will be FP.  Simply a question of how much work you want for the performance.  I suggest an abstract type that you code quickly one way (FP) and then migrate to optimized routines as performance dictates.